# Why is this Jquery not posting?

Tags: php, jquery, html

```
**HTML**
<form name="dataPost" method="post" id="dataPost">
     <input name="startdate" type="text" data-format="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss" id="startdate" title="Start Date of Report" value="<?php echo Base_Date::sqlToMDYSlashesWithTime($timezone); ?>"  />
     <input name="enddate" type="text" data-format="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"  id="enddate" title="End Date of Report" value="<?php echo Base_Date::sqlToMDYSlashesWithTime($timezone); ?>"  />
     <select name="cduid" multiple="multiple" style="height: 200px;" id="cduid">
 <?php foreach($energyStores as $energyStore) { ?>
 <option value="<?php echo $energyStore['energystore_cduid'] ?>"><?php echo $energyStore['energystore_cduid'] ?></option>
 <?php } ?>
 </select>
 <input name="generate" type='submit' id="generate" class="btn btn-primary" value="Generate Report" onClick="" />
</form>
```

**Jquery**

```
$("#dataPost").submit(function(){
    var startdate = $('#startdate').val();
    var enddate = $('#enddate').val();
    var cduid = $('#cduid').val();
    console.log (startdate, enddate, cduid);
    $.ajax({
       url: '../process/create_detail_cashbook_html.php',
       type:'POST',
       data: {startdate:startdate, enddate:enddate, cduid:cduid}   
    }).done(function(data) {
    });
   return false;
});
```

On hitting submit button none of my data is being posted. As I am new to all of this I struggle to understand other peoples code sorry if this is a duplicate.

This is what I have so far, the php page that loads is looking for this data but is not finding it.

Comment: "On hitting submit button none of my data is being posted" — How did you determine this?

Comment: What *does* happen? You have a console.log statement in there. Is it running? Is it logging the data you expect?

Comment: php error message says that cduid etc are undefined

Comment: console log says nothing

Comment: Would it make a difference if submit button is running another event

Comment: You're already using your browser's console. Please find the "Net" tab as next debugging step.

Comment: any error in your browser console

Comment: Replace `{startdate:startdate, enddate:enddate, cduid:cduid}` by `$(this).serialize()`

Comment: do you mean that you have multiple bindings like `$('#dataPost').submit(...)`?

Comment: Previous to this code I had a query which loaded the php using the same button

Comment: Paul Rad the replacement you gave me worked, can I use this same jquery to load the page it was posted to?